# How can I clear AutoSuggestBox items

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an AutoSuggestBox and its ItemSource is bounded from my VM.

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="MyBox" Grid.Row="1" GotFocus="MyBox_GotFocus"
                            QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search"
                            QuerySubmitted="MyBox_QuerySubmitted"
                            TextMemberPath="Description"
                            Header="Search"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SearchMatches}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource SearchAutoSuggestBoxStyle}" 
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchItemTemplate}"/>
```

So lets say it is like this:

[image]

How can i delete/clear its items/Suggestions on my Void Method?

```
MyBox.Items.Clear() // this shows Catastrophic failure error
```

Thanks

Comment: `SearchMatches.Clear()`.

Comment: @JustinXL lol too much code for today , I got confused for a simple problem xD , can you please Add that as Answer so i can mark it as Answer Thanks

Comment: Yeah that happens to us all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't want to interact with `Items` directly when you are using data binding. Try `Clear` on your underlying collection property instead.

```
SearchMatches.Clear();
```